# Can't find windows form by Alt + Tab during Visual Studio 2017 debugging on Windows 10

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2017, windows-10, visual-studio-debugging

I have a Windows Form project. When I start debug on Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10, the form opens behind the Visual Studio and I can't reach the form by Alt + Tab. I should minimize Visual Studio or pop it up from Task Manager.

Is there any way to do this by Alt + Tab? And is this a Visual Studio bug on Windows 10 ?

Comment: Do you have something like `SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE`/`HWND_BOTTOM` or similar? You could add `#if DEBUG (...)`.

Comment: @Jimi No, I don't have such a thing.

Comment: Possibly, show what you have, then. Are you modifying in any way the behavior of this Form? `WindowsState`, `ShowInTaskBar`, `TopMost`, code in the `Activated/OnActivated` event/override etc.? Something else?

Comment: @Jimi `ShowInTaskBar` solved my problem. It was false and I set it as true. Thank you so much :)

Comment: A `#if DEBUG / #else / #endif` block, as mentioned before, can be used to alter the behavior of some properties when a debugger is attached to your process. You can set some properties that are only useful when the executable *runs free* in the `#else` section. Unless leaving `ShowInTaskBar = false` was just an oversight.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to do this by Alt + Tab? And is this a Visual Studio
>   bug on Windows 10 ?

I'm not sure about what `can't reach the form by Alt + Tab` mean, do you mean that you can't see the form when `Alt+Tab` or can't display the form after choosing the form when Alt+Tab?

I tested it in VS2017+Win10, and the `Alt+Tab` always worked. So it's not a VS bug on windows10.

Here're steps that help to check and resolve that issue:

1.Check if you have some code to affect the normal behavior. An easy way is to create a new winform project, debug it and check if the issue persists. If the issue not occurs in new project, I think you must `set some property for Form1's property window` or write some code in your current project that caused this issue. Also, check what's the result if you `start without debugging the program`.

2.Reset all debug-related settings by `Tools-->Import and Export settings-->Reset all settings`.

3.[Repair VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) and make sure your VS has updated to latest 15.9.17 version.

Comment: `do you mean that you can't see the form when Alt+Tab`. Yes this is exactly what I mean. I can't see the form when Alt+Tab. If I minimize the vs2017 or select 'bring to front' option on task manager, I can see it. But I don't want to do that every time during debugging.

Comment: Also, I have latest VS2017 version. Btw, it isn't a simple Winform app. The form inherits from core system base form and I am not sure which property I should check that can effect this situation. Also, there wasn't any problem when my OS is Windows 7.